# Empty Methods in C# System.String Class (and others)

Tags: c#

I've been learning `C#` for about a year now. Thanks to Visual Studio's "Go To Definition" option, I noticed recently that the `System.String` class is filled with empty methods; they have no method body that says "do something".

After doing some searching, I can't find a good answer to how this works. My initial thought was that other classes inherit `System.String` and override these methods, but the class is [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx). According to MSDN:

> the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it.

So, how do *empty* methods in classes like `System.String`, such as

- `public bool StartsWith(string value);`
- `public int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count);`

and the many other methods/overloads in these classes, know what to do? I could guess that the compiler has some information on this, but that would simply be a guess. Am I even right in calling these methods? They all seem to do *something* to a string, but how? Where does this logic come from?

Comment: you need resharper or some other decompiler to see source code of methods

Comment: They're not empty, you just don't have the source code (or pdb file) to see what they contain. They have been compiled (turned from source code to machine code) so the you can only see the meta data, not the source. If you load the symbols (from a symbol server),decompile them or view the source (.Net is open source now) you will be able to see what they do.

Comment: You could also see source code on the [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c).

Comment: You can use a third party tool like ILSpy to disassemble assemblies, or you can enable source code retrieving for BCL classes directly from MS following these instructions : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7bc17ae3-6480-439c-bec4-66be22dcfe02/obtaining-debug-symbol-pdb-files-for-net-framework-452?forum=clr

Comment: This is absolutely correct! It didn't occur to me that the code would just be hidden from me, and my brain headed down the "everything is magic" path. Thanks for clearing this up! The question linked by @Liam does actually answer my question, though I didn't know that's what I was looking for. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If the duplicate answers your question, you should now have a yellow bar at the top of this question, saying something like "this answers my question". If you click the link on that it will close this as a duplicate. Glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is not source code of `String` class, it's the [metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcd8txaw(v=vs.110).aspx). It's the same information Intellisense shows.

If you want to see the source code of `String` class,  it's [available online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c)

Answer (score 2):

When you jump to definition on a class that you do not own/control, then Visual Studio will show you it's metadata. Essentially the contract by which the class agrees to, similar to if it had an interface.

You can download [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to see the actual implementation if you're curious what it is doing. The location of the DLL to decompile with ILSpy is give to you at the top of the metadata view in VS

[image: metadata extracted from dll]